# Perl script to download a file from LAN

Tags: perl, download, lan

path is similar to this `\\pc1\folder1\folder2\file.bin`
Above is the shared folder on the network
and I have to save it to a path similar to `c:\Users\me\Desktop\file_copy.bin`

I am new to Perl and thus clear explanation of how it is happening will be appreciable.

Comment: Do you need to authenticate to \\pc1? This makes a big difference to your question. (e.g. does it ask you for a username and password).

Comment: no authentication is required

Comment: Well in which case - you probably don't need Perl at all, and can just use 'copy'.

Comment: actually i have to automate it and integrate it in some other Perl script

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Win32::FileOp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::FileOp) module, below is how you open the file, you can use the CopyFile option for downloading.

```
use Win32::FileOp qw/ Map /;

Map 'X:' => ' \\\\machine\\share', 
  { user => 'foo', passwd => 'bar' };

open FILE, 'x:/path/file.ext' or die "...";
```

Also check out [File::Fetch](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Fetch.html)